# JSON giving unwanted row index number - Active Record - Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, activerecord

I don't know why when I echo json_encode a query result set I get the number of the result row before each object. I just want to count the number of total rows returns and have them displayed only once in the beginning of the JSON string and then just the rows returns afterwards. I.e. using the following code:

```
               //...active record query
               $result = $this->db->get();

                $data = array();

                $count = 1;

                foreach($result->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data['count'] = $count;
                    $entry = array();
                    $entry['firstname'] = $row->first_name;
                    $entry['lastname'] = $row->last_name;
                    $entry['jobtitle'] = $row->title;
                    $entry['dept'] = $row->dept_name;
                    $entry['deptid'] = $row->dept_no;

                    if($row->emp_no == null)
                    {
                        $entry['ismanager'] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $entry['ismanager'] = 1;
                    }
                    $data[] = $entry;
                    $count++;
                }

                return $data;
```

and then json_encode it in the controller, I get:

```
{"count":35,"0":{"firstname":"Georgi","lastname":"Facello","jobtitle":"Senior Engineer","dept":"Development","deptid":"d005","ismanager":0},"1":{"firstname":"Kirk","lastname":"Facello","jobtitle":"Senior Engineer","dept":"Development","deptid":"d005","ismanager":0},....rest of the query results
```

What I don't want is the `"0"` and `"1"` etc, before the row results. I already have the total count of the returned results so I don't need the individual row numbers.

If someone could kindly help me out I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to serialize an array as JSON, it would become something like this:

```
[elem1, elem2, elem3, ...]
```

But if that "array" have other fields then it will be serialized as an object:

```
{"field":value, "0":elem1, "1":elem2, "2":elem3, ...}
```

Since there's no way to serialize `field` using the array syntax, and `json_encode` can not simply discard it, then it uses the object syntax. As stated in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> **Note:**
>
> When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

A possible workaround for this would be separating the count from the list of elements:

```
$data = array();
$list = array();
$data['list'] = list;

$count = 1;
foreach($result->result() as $row)
{
    $data['count'] = $count;
    $entry = array();
    ...
    $list[] = $entry;
    $count++;
}
```

That would serialize to something like:

```
{"count":35,"list":[{"firstname":"Georgi","lastname":"Facello","jobtitle":"Senior Engineer","dept":"Development","deptid":"d005","ismanager":0},{"firstname":"Kirk","lastname":"Facello","jobtitle":"Senior Engineer","dept":"Development","deptid":"d005","ismanager":0},....rest of the query results]}
```

Comment: Thanks that did fix it. Could you direct me to somewhere where I can learn what you've just explained about serialization? Thank you

Comment: @AZ1 The example #3 in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) shows how `json_encode` would behave when given an array with missing elements (or non-sequential elements). My common sense told me the same would happen if that array had "extra" fields (see also the notes in the end).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` on your `json_encode` which will always make your numerical index show up as a property.  You should show your `json_encode` step in your question.

If you turn option off and go with a default encoding, you will still need to nest your numerically indexed array in its own property or the numerical indexes will show up as properties in order to make valid JSON.  For perhaps do something like this when assigning your rows to the object:

```
$data['records'][] = $entry;
```